# Can Android ProductFlavors Link Same "externalNativeBuild"?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, abi, android-productflavors

I got 6 flavors and every time when I generate 6 apks, it cost much time. I found AS build "cmake info" in "externalNativeBuild" for each flavor.

this is my gradle config for productFlavors:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId APPLICATION_ID
    ...
    flavorDimensions "versionCode"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
           targets "cocos"
           arguments "-DRES_DIR=${RES_PATH}", "-DCOCOS_X_PATH=${COCOS_ENGINE_PATH}", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_LD=gold"
           cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char"
        }
    }
}

splits {
    abi {

        enable true

        reset()

        include "arm64-v8a","armeabi-v7a"
        universalApk false
    }
}

productFlavors {
    "000" {
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    "001" {
        versionCode 104
        versionName "1.0.4"
    }
    "002" {
        versionCode 102
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }
    "003" {
        versionCode 102
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }
    "004" {
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    "010" {
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "../CMakeLists.txt"
        buildStagingDirectory "${RES_PATH}/proj/build"
    }
}
```

I want all flavor link same lib.so that I can spend a bit time to generate my apks.
How can I do ?
Thanks.